# Better Alternative to django.contrib.comments

Tags: python, django, django-apps, django-comments

I am having a nightmare working with django default commenting app. I am trying to customize it and add it to div tags to each field and have not been able to find out how to do it so far :(

see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033268/django-comments-app-adding-each-field-of-comments-app-to-div-classes

Is there a better alternative of this app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the official document, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/comments/

Django’s comment framework has been deprecated and is no longer supported. Most users will be better served with a custom solution, or a hosted product like Disqus.

If you still want to work with the old comments app, the repo is available at https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments
You might want to customized as needed

However if you want to use another apps, you can use Disqus as alternative. https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus

Comment: Thanks, disqus seems to be more suited live environment, I am testing the app on a local environment. Can disqus app work on local environment as well? Are there any other alternatives as well? Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Should be able to, just like many other 3rd party service integration.

Comment: Thanks Yeo. I have checked online there isn't much support available for django localhost integration with disqus

Comment: I'm not sure how localhost development can be an issue for the live production development. I believe you can just create another disqus application under different site name (e.g. localhost.foobar, etc...). I believe this is the case because disqus is just a client side integration. It is independent of what your server is. (it may be your local home server, or local development server or your production server)

Comment: Thank you, I searched around a bit and got the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives as per my personal experience with pros and cons:

1. Disqus - Very user friendly, supports a wide range of social media apps but not free
2. Facebook Comments - User friendly, free but only supports facebook. If users does not have facebook account, they cannot comment

Hence, i used [WidgetPack Comments](https://widgetpack.com/comment-system). Its very user friendly, self-hosted and easy to use. There is a step by step tutorial on its usage here
[Step by Step Tutorial](https://www.learninjava.com/react-widgetpack-free-disqus-alternative/).

If you are a reactjs developer, there is an npm module available. This allows to implement it using just a couple of lines of code: [react-widgetpack-comments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-widgetpack-comments)

Answer (score 0):

Django Comments is still alive, but in a seperate repository. You find the documentation here:

- https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For a quick start of the comments app, follow these initial steps (see above docu):

```
pip install django-contrib-comments
```

Enable the “sites” framework by adding 'django.contrib.sites' to INSTALLED_APPS and defining SITE_ID=1 (assuming you use just one domain in your current Django project), and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]'].

Install the comments framework by adding 'django_comments' to INSTALLED_APPS.

Run manage.py migrate so that Django will create the comment tables.
Add the comment app’s URLs to your project’s urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Within the templates you use then the related template tag, more about this and addtional options you find in the docu.